# how to use PublishSubject to Update UI before Next();

Tags: rx-java

at first. I use this way to update UI.

```
RetrofitHelper.getInstance().getGankDaily()
               .getInfo(page)
               .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
               .doOnSubscribe(new Action0() {
                @Override
                public void call() {
                    ／/shwo Progressbar
                }
            }).subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
              .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
              .subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Integer integer) {
                        //hide progressbar
                        })
```

Now, I want to use subject to replace this code.but I can not to `show progressbar` at the UI thread.

```
InfoGet = new Func1<GankType, Observable<Integer,x>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<x> call(Integer page) {
        return RetrofitHelper.getInstance().getGankDaily().
                getInfo(page)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }
};                                                         
subject.flatmap(InfoGet)
//.doOnSubscribe(show progressbar).subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .share();

public void loadmore(int page){
             subject.next(page);
}
result.compose(new HandleErrorTransformer())//handler error
                        .subscribe(new Action1())//show progressbar
```

`doOnSubscribe` only called at first and`donext`need a `new Action1()` .
So Ｉcan not to find a good way to solve this problem。 
I am a beginner of rxjava.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make progressBar be visible on some event (click or something) and then gone, when response came:

You can create separate `PublishSubject` just for progressBar visibility
`final PublishSubject<Boolean> progressSubject = PublishSubject.create();`
and somewhere subscribe to it:

```
 progressSubject.subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public void call(Boolean isVisible) {
             // make progressBar VISIBLE or GONE according to isVisible
      }
 });
```

Than, in this "event" just doing

```
 clickObservable
      .doOnNext(new Action1<Boolean>() {
           @Override
           public void call(Boolean isVisible) {
                  progressSubject.onNext(true);
           }
        })
      .//someSubscription...
```

And the same action in place where you receive response `progressSubject.onNext(false);`